# aws fargate and network costs

Tags: aws-fargate, amazon-elb

As per this [page](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/faqs/), AWS Fargate pricing is calculated based on vCPU & Memory consumption. However, while configuring the cluster, I picked "load balancer" as well. Does it mean that I would pay for "Network Load Balancer LCU" too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS load balancers are an add-on for Fargate. You will pay for the load balancer (per hour + LCU).